First-order system differential equation initial conditions
I am studying systems controls and in exploring first order systems I got confused on how to properly model a system with initial conditions.
This is the differential equation for a first order without dead time:
$$
\tau \frac{dy}{dt}+y(t)=Ku(t)
$$
Where $y(t)$ is the system response, $u(t)$ is the system input, $K$ is the gain and $\tau$ is the time constant of the system. For sake of simplicity, I will examine unit step inputs as the Laplace Transform of those is easy and then the $K$ and $\tau$ get their logical meaning. To solve the ODE I'll use the Laplace Transform:
$$
\mathcal{L}\{\tau \frac{dy}{dt}+y(t)\}=\mathcal{L}\{Ku(t)\}\\
\rightarrow\tau[sY(s) -Y(0^-)] + Y(s) = \frac{K}{s}
$$
I can choose $y(0) = 0$ and make life simpler to get:
$$
Y(s) = \frac{1}{s} \frac{K}{\tau s  + 1}\\
Y(s) = \frac{K}{s} - \frac{K\tau}{\tau s + 1} = \frac{K}{s} - \frac{K}{s + 1/\tau} \\
\rightarrow y(t) = \mathcal{L}^{-1}\{Y(s)\} = K(1 - e^{-t/\tau})
$$
Now what if there's an initial condition, say $y(t)$ represents temperature so $y(0) = T_0$ will be the ambient temperature. Then the solution to the ODE only changes by adding the inverse Laplace transform of $\frac{\tau T_0}{\tau s + 1}$:
$$
y(t) = K(1 - e^{-t/\tau}) + \mathcal{L}^{-1}\{ \frac{\tau T_0}{\tau s + 1}\}\\
\rightarrow{} y(t) = K(1- e^{-t/\tau}) + T_0 e^{-t/\tau}
$$
I think the math was done right however when looking at real world implementations (software) of systems like this (i.e PID control models in Matlab or PLC software), all they do is add the initial condition to $y(t)$:
$$
y(t) = K(1- e^{-t/\tau}) + T_0
$$
And graphing both solutions indeed shows that the second way of implementing the initial conditions is the correct one!
Graphs of both solutions
Am I thinking wrong of how initial conditions must be considered when using Laplace transforms? Should I have instead used an ODE that embodies this initial condition? A numerical implementation could take into account $T_0$ if one solves the following ODE with Euler's method or a Runge Kutta method:
$$
\tau \frac{dy}{dt}+ [y(t)-T_0]=Ku(t)
$$
Any input is appreciated. Thanks!

Your first approach is the correct one for considering the initial condition. The second one does not "add an initial condition", rather adds an "operational point" $T_0$ around which the system evolves.  In that latter case, $y(t)$ governed by the differential equation describes the relative value of the temperature around $T_0$. This is something that arises when linear systems are obtained from the linearization of a nonlinear system.

$y(t)=K(1-e^{-t/\tau}) + T_0$ is not a solution to the differential equation... you would have $\tau y'(t) +y(t) = K + T_0$.

@KBS by adding an operation point around which the system evolves then what is being done is something like Newton's law of cooling $T'(t) = k  (T - T_0)$, right? This would actually make more sense regarding the physical modeling, i.e what we care is relative change of $y(t)$. How is this a linearization of a nonlinear system though?

@PierreCarre which would make the differential equation describe relative temperature change by $\tau y'(t) + (y(t)-T_0) = K$, so the issue was how I incorrectly formulated the ODE in the first place!

Yes, you can do something like that, but this is different in the general case. Regarding linearization, there are many resources online that you can look at.
